# Change the unit of X-axis to Hz in LTspice

Tags: ltspice, frequency

How can I change the x-axis to Hz? I need it for frequency.

[image]

Comment: You can't. You should run a frequency response measurement. It's a different process. Check the tutorials.

Answer (score 7):

That depends on what kind of plot you want.

If you want a plot of level vs. frequency, like a Bode plot, you have to run an ***AC analysis***. First, you have to feed your circuit with a signal source with it's ***AC Amplitude*** parameter set, usually this is set to 1, this will give you a reference level of 0 dB. Then, edit your simulation command and choose ***AC analysis***, set the sweep to Octave, set the number of points to something like 200 (the more points the better the resolution, 200 is generally enough) and then enter your start and stop frequencies, for audio you might use something like 1 Hz to 100 kHz. You can't enter zero for the start, if you need a very low start frequency (as it appears you will as your signal looks to be around 1 Hz) you have to enter something like 1 mHz. Run the analysis and click on a point in the circuit to plot, usually the output, but it could be any point. You will get a plot of amplitude vs. frequency. This is useful for finding the frequency response of filters and amplifiers.

If you want a spectral plot you run a ***transient analysis*** and then right click on the plot and choose ***view*** and then ***FFT***. In the FFT settings you can just click OK to use the defaults, or you can change the settings, usually you would pick a Windowing Function, ***Hann*** tends to work well for audio signals.

If you just want to know the frequency of a repetitive waveform such as a sine wave you can click and drag in the waveform. This will give you a selection box, drag the box so that the left and right sides are 1 cycle of the waveform apart, for example on a sine wave you might click at the top of one peak and drag to the top of the next peak. In the status bar at the bottom of the window it will give some information about the area you have dragged, including frequency. Alternatively you can set two cursors and adjust them to be 1 cycle apart. Click the trace name at the top of the plot pane twice, then you can click and drag the crosshair cursors that appear on the plot.

Comment: i want a V = f(Hz) and all i can get is either a V=f(s) or dB = f(Hz)

Comment: @MaryamElYaagoubi Not sure exactly what you mean. In the FFT you can right click the left axis and change it to logarithmic to get voltage vs. frequency instead of dB vs. frequency, is that what you want?

Comment: i want i the normal diagramto be with Amplitude in mV and Frequency in Hz not the FFT

Comment: @MaryamElYaagoubi If you mean you want to show the sine waveform but have the x-axis show frequency that's not possible. Such a plot would be meaningless. If you want a plot of the frequency response of a circuit look at the AC analysis. I've added some additional instructions that I overlooked before. I've also added how to find the frequency of a waveform, so have a look at that as well.

Answer (score 2):

In a transient analysis:
Click on view menu and select "FFT"

Else do an AC analysis

Comment: there is no frequency in FFT @jasen and i can't use an AC analysis because i want amplitude = f(frequency)

Comment: @Maryam An AC analysis results in a plot of amplitude vs frequency. If that is not what you want then please explain exactly what you do want: what parameter on the X axis vs what parameter on the Y axis.

Comment: @Barry i want amplitude in mV in Y axis and Frequency Hz in X axis

Comment: @MaryamElYaagoubi Turn your screen 90 degrees.